# How to opitmize view rendering in Ruby On Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization

I have a rails app which shows the following log for a single action

```
Completed in 587ms (View: 415, DB: 29) | 200 OK [http://localhost/]
```

its taking 415 ms to render the view layer. Is there any way to optimize view rendering in rails ?
I am a beginner in ruby on rails.

I have render call like this on a page(written in HAML) that showed me the above log time. I want to optimize the rendering of these partials

```
  - auctions.each do |auction|
    = render :partial => "/shared/vertical_item", :object => auction,:inline => true
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A very nice way to optimize views is by using Fragment and Page Caching. But be careful about overdoing it.

Comment: my problem is with rendering parials.. let me update my question to explain the situation

Comment: try switching on the ugly mode in haml

Answer (score 0):

I could be confused, but i do not know what the `:inline => true` is supposed to do. According to me `:inline` is used to render inline erb without using a template, e.g.

```
  render :inline => "<%= 'hello ' + name %>", :locals => { :name => "david" }
```

(from the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000464))

So i would suggest to remove that `:inline => true` and see if that helps.

Otherwise i would like to see that partial you are using.